# Unable to get access token via Client Credentials flow

Tags: rest-api, oauth

I am using Postman to make a request to my Salesforce domain:

[image: Example]

The response shown in the above example:

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "grant type not supported"
}
```

That is with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Then, if I move the data from Body into Params, I get the following response:

[image: Example]

```
{
    "access_token": "00D7Q00000D2HbY!AQ8AQNyz...",
    "signature": "9IMgiZLiUughUYuA7WlXUmqqdApG0aq60mkMj7VJhUE=",
    "scope": "Test openid",
    "instance_url": "https://curious-panda-tcxxxn-dev-ed.trailblaze.my.salesforce.com",
    "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D7Q00000D2HbYUAV/0057Q000007e7FIQAY",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "1686654589947"
}
```

Can anyone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong? As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5), I should be able to put the parameters in the Body to make the request more secure:

> To initiate the flow, the connected app posts its client credentials
> to the Salesforce token endpoint. You can include the client
> credentials as parameters in the body of the request. Or, for added
> security, put your client credentials in a Basic authorization header.

**EDIT:**

Please see also the headers I am using below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about 8 hours of testing etc. I found out that the Salesforce instances generated as Trailhead Playgrounds can not receive the OAuth requests with params in body. Any domain that ends with `trailblaze.my.salesforce.com` will return the `unsupported_grant_type` error.

I found out when I tested on a developer org where I received a successful response.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that what you are trying should work; here's a successful test I ran in Postman with the same config:
[image: Postman Screenshot]

There must be some other issue.  I would double check the client id/secret values in the body version.  Perhaps clear and re-type `client_credentials` in case there is a space or other non-printable pasted in there.

Comment: Thank you so much. At least I know it should work.